# How can I export more than one file with the same name in a jar?

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I have a project, which have some other projects as dependencies. All of these projects have a file named "forms.properties", in the source folder "src". I am getting these files with the following code:

```
Enumeration<URL> propFiles = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResources("forms.properties");
```

It works well when I run the project through Eclipse, because it finds all the property files. The problem is when I export it as a runnable jar, only the last "forms.properties" is exported, the other ones seems to be overwrite because they have the same name and they are in the same folder, only changing the project name.

Do you know how can I export it without having this overwrite effect?

Comment: How would you *expect* there to be multiple files at the same logical location? I would suggest giving each project a separate resources folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you turn everything into one jar, each file has a different folder.

When you build the application they have to have a different folders in the same jar or different names or be in different jars.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the way you read the files to have different locations (i.e. folders) and they will be exported correctly.